# php how to update file with highest values?

Tags: php, string, file, header, bin

So i've got a skript that reads data from a binary file and converst them to decimal adn writes that into a new file. The input file is updated every hour. The new file has to be updated every hour sas well. Currently i am trying to figure out, how to make PHP only update a file, when values coming from the original file rae higher than already existing values. Eg if my destination file has values 4,5,5,4,7 and the original file the values 3,2,3,2,4 i don't want it to update. However with values from the original file being something like 3,5,6,4,2 - i want the higher values, here the "6" to be written into the new file like this: 4,5,6,4,7 
Don't beat me, i know there's likely a simple solution to it, but can't think of a way.

Answer (score 0):

https://3v4l.org/SuNsI

```
$one = "4,5,5,4,7";
$two = "3,5,6,4,2";

$aone = explode(",", $one);
$atwo = explode(",", $two);

$result= "";
For($i=0;$i<count($aone);$i++){
    If($atwo[$i] > $aone[$i]){
        $result[] = $atwo[$i];
    }else{
        $result[] = $aone[$i];
    }
}

Var_dump($result);

$str = implode(",", $result);
Echo $str;
```

Edited to add how to rebuild the string.